# ConnectionString problem Entity-Framework

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string, visual-studio-2019

I have a Project with Entity Framework. On till yesterday everthing was working as expected. After an Update from Visual Studio 2019 to Version 16.6.1 i got the following error:

> SqlException: CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Zugriff verweigert) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Users\benjaPRWSolution2020.mdf'.

The funny thing is, in my opinion C:\Users\benjaPRWSolution2020.mdf **should be** C:\Users\benja\PRWSolution2020.mdf

also as referance my connnectionString what i didnt has changed since long time

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=PRWSolution2020;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Is there any possible workaround?

**Update:**
When i input

`attachdbfilename=&quot;C:\Users\benja\PRWSolution2020.mdf&quot;`

to my connectionString its working. But this can not be the solution.